# Multiple-valued field in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I have my model Room as follows:

```
eid = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I want to create another field user where user is a foreign key. Is to possible to create a field where multiple values can be added to a single row? For example: there are 3 users: user1,user2,user3.
Now, I want a row to look like:

```
{'eid':1,'name':'room1','user':[user1,user2,user3]}
```

Is the above scenario possible or do I need to create separate rows for each user?
Note: A **room** model can have multiple users, but a user cannot be part of multiple rooms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple foreign keys, you can use [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField). When you convert it to JSON, it will display as array, just like you wanted.

Comment: A room (model) can have multiple users, but a user cannot be part of multiple rooms. So, is that One-to-Many relationship or Many-to-One relationship?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a classical many-to-many relationship. As the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) say for that case, you could have your model Room as something like this:

```
eid = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

EDIT: since the OP has mentioned in a comment that one user must have only one room, but that a room may have many users, then their User model must have a ForeignKey field, as it is a [one-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

```
room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Possible values for the `on_delete` field may be checked [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: By using Foreign key, it will create a new row for each and every user. Multiple values can't be stored under a single field.

Comment: Well, each existing user's gonna have a room associated to them. Why is this a problem, though? It looks like the better way to model the available data.

Comment: Each existing user shouldn't have his own room. That is my problem here. Each room can have multiple users, but each user should have only one room. I am thinking of using Foreign Key where for each user, there will be a new row, in the following way  
    {'eid':1,'name':'room1','user':user1}
    {'eid':1,'name':'room1','user':user2}
    {'eid':1,'name':'room1','user':user3}

Comment: I still don't understand. You could filter all the users in a room using .objects.filter, and set the room foreign key, in the User model, as nullable, using `null=True` after its `on_delete` clause.